# Ionic React Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, calculator, react-hooks

This code to calculate a price used to work in class components before react JS was updated. Now im using useState instead of this.state and im having trouble getting my old code working. Im mainly having a hard time setting the state values and using them in the check price function.

**Im also getting an error**:

Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable....... `basePrice += basePrice * (percentage / 100)`

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated! THANK YOU!!

**OLD CODE**

```
 checkPrice = () => { 
      debugger;
       if(this.state.packageSelected === "one"){
        this.state.basePrice = 159.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "two"){
            this.state.basePrice = 416.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "three){
            this.state.basePrice = 199.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "four"){
            this.state.basePrice = 249.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "five"){
            this.state.basePrice = 299.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "six"){
            this.state.basePrice = 559.998;
       }if(this.state.propertySqft > 2500){
   let overage = this.state.propertySqft - 2000;
   let percentage = Math.floor(overage / 500) * 10;
   this.state.basePrice += this.state.basePrice * (percentage / 100);


  }
     this.setState({ totalPrice: Math.round(this.state.basePrice * 100) / 100 }); 
  }
```

**NEW CODE**

```
function checkPrice() { 
      debugger;
       if(packageSelected === "one"){
         setBasePrice(159.998);
       }else if(packageSelected === "two"){
         setBasePrice(416.998);
       }else if(packageSelected === "three"){
         setBasePrice(199.998);
       }else if(packageSelected === "four"){
         setBasePrice(249.998);
       }else if(packageSelected === "five"){
         setBasePrice(299.998);
       }else if(packageSelected === "six"){
         setBasePrice(559.998);   
       }if(propertySqft > 2500){
   let overage = propertySqft - 2000;
   let percentage = Math.floor(overage / 500) * 10;

    basePrice += basePrice * (percentage / 100);
  }
     setTotalPrice(Math.round(basePrice * 100) / 100); 
  }
```

Comment: Don't directly mutate your state, I am guessing you declared your `basePrice` like `const [basePrice, setBasePrice]`, and you are doing `basePrice += basePrice * (percentage / 100);`. You are trying to assign a value to a `const`

Comment: Correct thats exactly what I did. So should I create another state like newBasePrice and make it  setNewBasePrice(basePrice * (percentage / 100))

Comment: Why would you need that as a state ? Also I would suggest you to create a map of `packageSelected` to `price` instead. Your code looks repetitive and very uncomfortable to read.